# Can not connect to ssh over IPsec VPN

Tags: linux, ssh, vpn, linux-networking

I am trying to reach a machine via an ike IPsec (shrew soft) VPN connection. 
I can ping the remote machine:

```
$ ping 10.3.6.10
PING 10.3.6.10 (10.3.6.10) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.3.6.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=3.05 ms
64 bytes from 10.3.6.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.55 ms
```

Traceroute is also possible ...

```
$ traceroute 10.3.6.10
traceroute to 10.3.6.10 (10.3.6.10), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  the.vpnurl (153.96.2.181)  0.987 ms  0.978 ms  0.970 ms
 2  the.hostname (10.3.6.10)  1.617 ms  1.595 ms  1.596 ms
```

Ssh obviously gets a connection. Can even discover the remote server type. But then ssh does not open ...

```
ssh -v user@10.3.6.10
OpenSSH_7.1p2, OpenSSL 1.0.2f  28 Jan 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Connecting to 10.3.6.10 [10.3.6.10] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 10.3.6.10:22 as 'user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
```

Does anyone know what I can do to solve this?

(I am running Manjaro, an archlinux derivative)

Comment: What do the server logs say? Also, any IPsec-related error messages?

Comment: I can not find any special errors in the logs